# Error de conversión al convertir el valor nvarchar al tipo de datos int

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Estoy creando un json para guardar 2 valores de un form que tienen el mismo nombre (`data`) para que cuando se guarden 2 filas en la tabla en vez de una sola al mismo tiempo.

**Esa estructura esta creada así y no puede ser editada.**

En principio funciona, pero al final me da un error que ya no estoy muy convencido que sea problema de Laravel, por lo que no se por donde tirar.

He probado a guardar dos veces el valor "1" a ver que salía, y ha salido el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error de conversión al convertir el valor nvarchar '["1","1"]' al tipo de datos int. (SQL: insert into [convocatorias_proceso_preguntas] ([ID_convocatoria_proceso]) values (["1","1"]))

Más sencilla no puede ser la DB y el proyecto en si, osea que ya no se por donde tirar.

##### DB Structure

> - ID (INT, Primary Key, AUTOINCREMENT)
> - Data (INT)

##### `DataController.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\data;

use App\Data;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreDataPost;

class DataController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('data', ['Data' => new Data()]);
    }

    public function store(StoreDataPost $request)
    {
        $json = json_encode($request->get('data')); 
        Data::create(['data' => $json]);
    }
}
```

##### `Data.php`

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Data extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'table_data';

    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';

    protected $fillable = [
        'data'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getDataAttribute()
    {
       return json_decode($this->data);
    }
}
```

##### `StoreDataPost.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreDataPost extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'data.*' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

##### `data.blade.php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Send Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ route("store") }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        
        {{-- Data in field 1 in DB --}
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="data[]" id="data">
        </div>

        {{-- Data in field 2 in DB --}
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="data[]" id="data">
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estas tratando de meter un array dentro de una columna integer a palo seco y no lo esta interpretando ni como string, ni como integer, ni con nada, has de recorrer ese array antes de nada.

Prueba a sustituir esta parte de tu código con el siguiente:

```php
public function store(StoreDataPost $request)
{
    foreach (request('data') as $val) {
        Data::create(['data' => $val]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Increíble, era eso. Muchísimas gracias compañero!

Answer (score 0):

Tiene toda la pinta de que intentas guardar un valor String o nvarchar en campos que realmente son int.

Te recomiendo que cambies el tipo de ambos input de la siguiente manera:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Send Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ route("store") }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
    
        {{-- Data in field 1 in DB --}
        <div>
            <input type="number" name="data" id="data">
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Edición:

Se elimina 1 de los inputs para poder enviar datos individuales.

Comment: Nada, sigue dando el mismo error, y lo he puesto idéntico a tu corrección..

Comment: Vale, creo que tu problema, no es que guardes datos de distinto tipo, creo que estás informando directamente un vector y se espera un int, de ahí esto: Error de conversión al convertir el valor nvarchar '["1","1"]' al tipo de datos int. Por lo que además de cambiar el tipo del input, deberías cambiar la forma de pasar los datos entre el form y el controlador.

Comment: ¿Y como se haría eso? Entiendo la teoría pero no caigo en que debería cambiar.

Comment: Edito la respuesta, pero no se si será correcta, no puedo probarlo ahora mismo. Mira a ver si te sirve pasando sólo 1 campo y luego prueba a pasarle 2, y vas jugando desde ahí.